# PHP in_array function, why this doesn't work?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array, generated from a database:

```
do {
    $rsvp_array[$row_rsRSVP['rsv_guest']] = array(
        'id' => $row_rsRSVP['rsv_id'],
        'guest' => $row_rsRSVP['rsv_guest'],
        'confirmed' => $row_rsRSVP['rsv_confirmed']
    );
} while ($row_rsRSVP = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsRSVP));
```

It's vey fine, with print_r() I get this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [guest] => 1
            [confirmed] => 1
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [guest] => 15
            [confirmed] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [guest] => 5
            [confirmed] => 1
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [guest] => 10
            [confirmed] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [guest] => 6
            [confirmed] => 0
        )

)
```

So I know that the array is working.

Now I need to see if a number is in the main array, i.e.:

```
if (in_array(15, $rsvp_array)) { echo 'OK'; }
```

And well, this doesn't work! Number 15 is the second key of the array, but no luck!
Where am I wrong?
Thanks in advance for the answers...

Comment: `do{}while()` is not suitable for fetching data, always use `while(){}`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[**`in_array()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) will search in the **values** -- and not the keys.

You should either :

- use [**`array_key_exists()`**](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists) : `if (array_key_exists(15, $rsvp_array)) {...}`
- or use [**`isset()`**](http://fr.php.net/isset) to test whether a certain key is set : `if (isset($rsvp_array[15])) {...}`
- or *(bad idea)* use [**`array_keys()`**](http://fr.php.net/array_keys) to get the keys, and use [**`in_array()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) on that array of keys.

Comment: @Felix : indeed ; I've edited my answer to say it's a bad idea -- and it's now the third proposal *(I've added isset as a second proposal, so the last one is the 'bad' one)*

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are looking for [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) in_array used to check if the value is in array not for key.

```
if (array_key_exists(15,$rsvp_array))
{
  echo "ok";
}
```

or check it with isset

```
isset($rsvp_array[15])
```

Answer (score 2):

`in_array()` are only looking at the values of an array, but you want to know, if a specific key is set

```
if (array_key_exists(15, $rsvp_array)) { echo 'OK'; }
```

or

```
if (isset($rsvp[15])) { echo 'OK'; }
```

The second one is sufficient in most cases, but it doesnt work, if the value is `null`.